# Superman comic where he fights a progressively stronger alien creature

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification

In which comic issue does Superman fight an alien creature with greyish-mud coloured skin that progressively grows stronger the longer it remains on Earth? The creature was very strong, making Superman use a considerable amount of his true strength. I'm quite sure it's not Doomsday.

Additional details I remember are the alien being born here while its mother died or something along those lines and its skin slowly turning tougher and stronger. It was definitely bipedal and humanoid but had a very thick neck, I think. Superman also flew it into a mountain something like half a continent away. It slowly learned how to speak and had some form of mental powers, if my memory serves. The artwork style and when I remembered it was around 2000's or later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it thanks to a reddit user by the username superschaap81 ! The creature in question was **[Subjekt-17](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Subjekt-17_(New_Earth))**.

[image: Subjekt-17 battles Superman]

[Subjekt-17 appeared in Superman #654, #655, #656, #662 and #667](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Subjekt-17_(New_Earth)/Appearances).